# SMART disabled on new MacBook Pro 13 Retina (ForceTouch)

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

I just wanted to see some of the SSD parameters on my freshly purchased MacBook Pro retina and found out that SMART support is obviously disabled by default.

Is this intended and if so, why? I'm using smartmontools to read out the information…

```
> $ smartctl -a /dev/disk0                                                     
smartctl 6.4 2015-06-04 r4109 [x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-15, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     APPLE SSD SM0256G
Serial Number:    *censored*
LU WWN Device Id: *censored*
Firmware Version: BXW1JA0Q
User Capacity:    251,000,193,024 bytes [251 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4c
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Thu Jul  2 08:58:52 2015 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Disabled
```

**EDIT:**

It would be great if someone else could also confirm that SMART is disabled by default. You simply have to install **[smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org)** via **[brew](http://brew.sh)**.

```
brew install smartmontools
```

and then check the status via

```
smartctl -a /dev/disk0
```

**UPDATE:**

Without changing anything, I noticed today that it apparently switched itself to `enable`. I'm not sure when this happened but I installed several Mac OS X updates, so probably this was fixed by (at least) one of them. Here is the new output:

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     APPLE SSD SM0256G
Serial Number:    *censored*
LU WWN Device Id: *censored*
Firmware Version: BXW1JA0Q
User Capacity:    251,000,193,024 bytes [251 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4c
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Jan 25 09:09:44 2016 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

Comment: Anyone confirm this is the case for multiple MacBooks?

Comment: @agentroadkill my MacBook Air (11") has SMART Enabled.

Comment: @DDPWNAGE, that's from the factory? We'd need to know your exact model as well as septi's model number to confirm.

Comment: @agentroadkill Here's the raw output from running `smartctl -a /dev/disk0`: [http://pastebin.com/hSLVJTJz](http://pastebin.com/hSLVJTJz)

Comment: MacBook Pro 13" Retina Late 2012 (A1425): Disabled from factory.

Comment: Macbook Pro 2015, Big Sur. It was disabled, no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

You can reenable SMART for a volume by typing the command:

```
sudo smartctl -s on /dev/disk0
```

Comment: I know how to reenable it. The question is, why is it disabled by default? There must be a reason…

Comment: Replying to an old thread, but could be useful: OWC SSD-equipped MacBook here, SMART disabled by default. Don't know why.